# Using iOS UNUserNotificationCenter, How to set start and end time of alarms?

Tags: ios, swift

Using iOS UNUserNotificationCenter Can I set start and end of alarms time?

For example, I want set alarm 7:00 AM to 10:00 PM everyday and repeat interval is 30 minutes.

like this app.

[image]

My code is below .

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [id.uuidString])
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(repeatTypeFromNow * 60), repeats:true)
let  request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id.uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Is it possible on serverless environment?

Comment: your code repeats the notification every 60 seconds. have you tried running it? what happened? there isn't enough information here.

Comment: How about this. Create a global variable that checks if notification is enabled or not. If notification is enabled create a notification observer, then check current time. Create 2 global variables to store the start and end time. If the current time is between those 2 values call a function to create a notification post. When this triggers, it should goto function of that notification. Inside that , add your code to present alarm and initiate a delayed function with 30mins delay to call the function to check current time. If current time is between the specified time, then redo this !